# 'cannot extract element from a scalar' when order by id is DESC

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, where-clause, postgresql-9.3

I have a PostgreSQL 9.3.10 database, a table with 15842 records and use Intellij for making queries.
I want to query some recent data from JSON column (named 'data').

My query is that simple:

```
select data->'header'
from some_table
order by id desc
```

The problem is that I get:

> [22023] ERROR: cannot extract element from a scalar

when I use `desc` order. When I use `asc` the query does not fail and at least first 500 records are received.

For me it looks like some recent record could have invalid JSON. If so, how can I ignore bad record and still perform the query with `DESC` ordering? Or how to identify broken JSON record?

I also thought that it can be caused by null data but `select * from table where data is null` does not show any results.

UPD: The type of the 'data' column is `json`. I found that there are rows having json data serialized to string (because of faulty backend). So instead of normal json **object**: `{}` the values is a quoted object **string** `"{}"`. Detected by the following query: `select data from some_table where data::text not like '{%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by ActiveRecord version update which caused a Ruby object receiving `to_json` explicitly to be written as a single string which is a valid JSON data too (Postgres calls it: "scalar" in error message).
That's why an error only appeared in query using `by id desc` (only for new records created after ActiveRecord update). Here is a note on change in ActiveRecord: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/835246e622dc0431af3cb951db22ef78876006af

So instead of `{"header": "value"}` it was written as `"{\"header\": \"value\"}"`.
The database was fixed with the following query:

```sql
update some_table 
set data = REPLACE(TRIM(BOTH '"' from data::text), '\"', '"')::JSON 
where data::text like '"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem indicates that the `data` column was not created with the proper datatype to start with. If it was `json` or `jsonb`, then the faulty data would have been rejected at insert time.

I don't think Postgres has a built-in function to check the validity of a JSON string. You would need to create one, like:

```
create or replace function is_jsonb(js text)
    returns boolean
as $$
begin
    return (js::jsonb is not null);
exception 
    when others then return false;  
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can use it in a query:

```
select *
from mytable
where not is_jsonb(data);
```

Depending on the datatype of `data`, additional casting might be needed, like:

```
where not is_jsonb(data::text);
```

Comment: The column data type was `json`. Now I see that the problem is that some rows have json serialized to string (`"{}"`). It is still JSON, but string and not an object which I expect

Comment: @Kirill: maybe you want: `where not is_jsonb((data->'header')::text)`?